# Getting each DIV contained in my list items to stay exactly centered at 1024px wide upon hover of list item

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my DIV's that are contained within each list item to stay exactly centered at 1024px wide when each list item is hovered over.

I also need the right 3 secondary nav links to be right-aligned instead of left aligned, so that when user hovers, the nav menu will be immediately accessible (instead of trying to "jump" to the left side of menu. I am wanting alignment functionality similar to this site: https://www.michaeljfox.org/

Code is below and working demo is below further:

```
    <div id="nav-wrapper-sot">
    <div id="navmenu-sot">

    <ul class="nav-sot" >

    <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a>
     <div class="about_content">
       <a href="">Vision & Policies</a><a href="">Notable Members</a><a href="">History</a><a href="">Affiliates</a><a href="">Financial Information</a>    
            </div>





    </li>
    <li id="members"><a href="#">Members & Groups</a>
     <div class="members_content">
           <a href="">Membership</a><a href="">Postdoctoral</a><a href="">Graduate Students</a>  
            </div>
    </li>
    <li id="meetings"><a href="#">Meetings & Events</a>
    <div class="meetings_content">
             <a href="">Annual Meeting</a><a href="">Events Calendar</a><a href="">Sponsored Meetings</a><a href="">Co-Hosted Events</a>  
            </div>
    </li>
    <li id="pubs"><a href="#">Publications & News</a>
    <div class="pubs_content">
       <a href="">Annual Meeting Publications</a><a href="">Newsroom</a><a href="">Advertising</a>    
            </div>
    </li>
    <li id="awards"><a href="#">Awards & Funding</a>
    <div class="awards_content">
              <a href="">Awards</a><a href="">Grants & Funding</a><a href=""> Endowment Fund</a>  
            </div>
    </li>
    <li id="careers"><a href="#">Careers</a>
    <div class="careers_content">
           <a href="">Job Bank</a><a href="">Mentor</a><a href="">Internships & Fellowships</a><a href="">Career Development Resources</a><a href="">Salary Surveys</a>     
            </div>
    </li>
    <li id="education"><a href="#">Education</a>
    <div class="education_content">
             <a href="">Continuing Education</a><a href="">Presentations & Webinars</a><a href="">Students</a><a href="">Educators</a><a href="">K-12 Outreach</a>  
            </div>
    </li>
    <li id="global"><a href="#">Global Programs </a>
    <div class="global_content">
             <a href="">International Grants</a><a href=""> Membership</a><a href="">Education Resources</a><a href="">News & Events</a><a href="">Global  Exchange Program</a>  
            </div>
    </li>
    <li id="mylinks"><a href="#">My Links</a>
    <div class="mylinks_content">
      <a href="">My Links links</a> 
            </div>
    </li>
    </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
    #nav-wrapper-sot {
        clear:both;
        width:100%; 
        background: #ff6633;
        margin 0 auto;
    }



      #navmenu-sot {

            margin 0 auto;
            width:100%;


    }


    #navmenu-sot > ul  {
        list-style-type: none;

        padding: 0px;
    }

     .nav-sot {  text-align:center;  }



    .nav-sot > li {
        padding: 0px;
        height: 30px;
        font-family:   Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: -0.5px;
        font-size: 14px;
      display:inline-block;
      background: #ff6633;
         border-right: 1px solid #D6D3D3;


    }

    .nav-sot > li > a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 32px;


    }




    #navmenu-sot  li:hover > a {
        color:#ff6633;
         padding:0px;
        display:block;
        background:white;
      font-weight:bold;
    }







    #about    {

        border-left:1px solid #D6D3D3;

    }


    #about   a {

        width: 75px;


    }

    #members a {

         width: 137px;
    }

    #meetings a {

        width: 138px;
    }

    #pubs a {

        width: 142px;
    }


    #awards a {

        width: 126px;
    }

    #careers a {

        width: 77px;
    }


    #education a {

        width: 80px;
    }

    #global a {

        width: 125px;
    }

    #mylinks a {
        background: #3399cc;
        color: #f2f5eb;
          width: 85px;
          border-right:none;
    }




      .about_content, .members_content, .meetings_content, .pubs_content, .awards_content, .careers_content, .education_content, .global_content, .mylinks_content 
      { 
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
       top:45px;

       border: 1px solid #ff6633;

        padding-top:12px;
        padding-bottom:12px;

        text-align:left;
        z-index:-1;
        width:1024px;
      }

       .about_content a, .members_content a, .meetings_content a, .pubs_content a, .awards_content a, .careers_content a, .education_content a, .global_content a, .mylinks_content a { 

         text-decoration:none;
         color:#ff6633;
         padding:12px;

         margin:0px;

       }

    #navmenu-sot li:hover .about_content, 
    #navmenu-sot li:hover .members_content, 
    #navmenu-sot li:hover .meetings_content,
    #navmenu-sot li:hover .pubs_content,
    #navmenu-sot li:hover .awards_content,
    #navmenu-sot li:hover .careers_content, 
    #navmenu-sot li:hover .education_content, 
    #navmenu-sot li:hover .global_content, 
    #navmenu-sot li:hover .mylinks_content 

    {

          display:block;

    }


    .nav-sot  li div a:hover {
      background-color:#ff6633;
      color:#FFFFFF;
    }
```

---

Demo:
http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/vEojjW/

Comment: Did you not ask the same /similar question before? Ironically I answered that question and was accepted as well. Now what happened?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214734/navbar-with-secondary-nav-in-horizontal-line-beneath/29219291#29219291

Comment: I explained my reasoning above for the similarity of these questions, but why this posting is unique. Should I just delete the previous question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214734/navbar-with-secondary-nav-in-horizontal-line-beneath

Comment: @trevoray - you don't have to delete the old one but reword this one and not make this question look and feel like the old one. or else it will be flagged as being duplicate

Comment: I've done the best I can to show that this question is different, but yes, it based off of same nav menu that I am trying to build from previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#nav-wrapper-sot {
 clear:both;
 width:100%; 
 background: #ff6633;
   margin 0 auto;
}



  #navmenu-sot {
  
  margin 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  
       
}

 
#navmenu-sot > ul  {
    list-style-type: none;
   
    padding: 0px;
}

 .nav-sot {  text-align:center;  }


  
.nav-sot > li {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family:   Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    font-size: 14px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: #ff6633;
     border-right: 1px solid #D6D3D3;
  
    
}

.nav-sot > li > a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
    
  
}



 
#navmenu-sot  li:hover > a {
    color:#ff6633;
  padding:0px;
    display:block;
 background:white;
  font-weight:bold;
}

 


 
 

#about    {
  
 border-left:1px solid #D6D3D3;
  
}


#about   a {
   
 width: 75px;
 
  
}

#members a {
   
  width: 137px;
}

#meetings a {
  
 width: 138px;
}

#pubs a {
    
 width: 142px;
}


#awards a {
  
 width: 126px;
}

#careers a {
   
 width: 77px;
}


#education a {
  
 width: 80px;
}

#global a {
   
 width: 125px;
}
 
#mylinks a {
    background: #3399cc;
    color: #f2f5eb;
   width: 85px;
   border-right:none;
}
 

 
 
  .about_content, .members_content, .meetings_content, .pubs_content, .awards_content, .careers_content, .education_content, .global_content, .mylinks_content 
  { 
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
   top:45px;
   
   border: 1px solid #ff6633;
   
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
    
    text-align:left;
    z-index:-1;
    width:1024px;
   margin: 0 0 0 -512px;
   left: 50%;
  }

   .about_content a, .members_content a, .meetings_content a, .pubs_content a, .awards_content a, .careers_content a, .education_content a, .global_content a, .mylinks_content a { 
     
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#ff6633;
     padding:12px;
    
     margin:0px;
     
   }
 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .about_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .members_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .meetings_content,
#navmenu-sot li:hover .pubs_content,
#navmenu-sot li:hover .awards_content,
#navmenu-sot li:hover .careers_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .education_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .global_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .mylinks_content 

{
    
   display:block;
     
}

#navmenu-sot li:hover .awards_content,
#navmenu-sot li:hover .careers_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .education_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .global_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .mylinks_content 

{
    
   text-align: right;
     
}


.nav-sot  li div a:hover {
  background-color:#ff6633;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-wrapper-sot">
<div id="navmenu-sot">

<ul class="nav-sot" >

<li id="about"><a href="#">About</a>
 <div class="about_content">
   <a href="">Vision & Policies</a><a href="">Notable Members</a><a href="">History</a><a href="">Affiliates</a><a href="">Financial Information</a>    
        </div>
  
  
 
  
  
</li>
<li id="members"><a href="#">Members & Groups</a>
 <div class="members_content">
       <a href="">Membership</a><a href="">Postdoctoral</a><a href="">Graduate Students</a>  
        </div>
</li>
<li id="meetings"><a href="#">Meetings & Events</a>
<div class="meetings_content">
         <a href="">Annual Meeting</a><a href="">Events Calendar</a><a href="">Sponsored Meetings</a><a href="">Co-Hosted Events</a>  
        </div>
</li>
<li id="pubs"><a href="#">Publications & News</a>
<div class="pubs_content">
   <a href="">Annual Meeting Publications</a><a href="">Newsroom</a><a href="">Advertising</a>    
        </div>
</li>
<li id="awards"><a href="#">Awards & Funding</a>
<div class="awards_content">
          <a href="">Awards</a><a href="">Grants & Funding</a><a href=""> Endowment Fund</a>  
        </div>
</li>
<li id="careers"><a href="#">Careers</a>
<div class="careers_content">
       <a href="">Job Bank</a><a href="">Mentor</a><a href="">Internships & Fellowships</a><a href="">Career Development Resources</a><a href="">Salary Surveys</a>     
        </div>
</li>
<li id="education"><a href="#">Education</a>
<div class="education_content">
         <a href="">Continuing Education</a><a href="">Presentations & Webinars</a><a href="">Students</a><a href="">Educators</a><a href="">K-12 Outreach</a>  
        </div>
</li>
<li id="global"><a href="#">Global Programs </a>
<div class="global_content">
         <a href="">International Grants</a><a href=""> Membership</a><a href="">Education Resources</a><a href="">News & Events</a><a href="">Global  Exchange Program</a>  
        </div>
</li>
<li id="mylinks"><a href="#">My Links</a>
<div class="mylinks_content">
  <a href="">My Links links</a> 
        </div>
</li>
</ul>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

That would be a fix anyway here is the lines that were added

```
 width: 1024px;
 margin: 0 0 0 -512px;
 left: 50%;
```

Ok here is an explanation how it works

x = child width = 1024px;
y = x / 2 = 602px;

left: 50%;
margin: 0 0 0 -y;

to explain why its different then what i put is because the links are not centered so i got the closest relevant number and as u can see its point accurate will work on all browsers.

for more information on how to center an absolute positioned element goto here
http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/
and go down to "Center An Absolutely Positioned Element" It has some other examples you can use.

As for the right alignment i just added

```
#navmenu-sot li:hover .awards_content,
#navmenu-sot li:hover .careers_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .education_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .global_content, 
#navmenu-sot li:hover .mylinks_content {
text-align: right;   
}
```

Hope this help! :D

Comment: thanks so much!! So glad someone was willing to help me despite the fact that I had a previous similar question.

Comment: quick question. The z-index is on there so the white background will "hide" the orange border at top. But when I try this on my develpment site, this z-index setting causes the secondary rollover to not "stick" when hovering over. Any ideas?

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. Another words something could be using a similar z-index that can cause this just change it around and see what you get